# Option clash for package tkz-tab

Tags: optional-arguments, option-clash, tkz-tab

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage[inline]{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

and it returns the LateX error `Option clash for package tkz-tab`.

I do find it kind of weird to call twice `tkz-tab`.

My questions are (beyond the fact that I'd like to get rid of the error message) :

1. does the `\usepackage[inline]{tkz-tab}` command allows to get the same thing then the `\usepackage{tkz-tab}` and more with `[inline]` option, or less because of that option, or something different, hence the option clash ?
2. What's the use of that `[inline]` option ?

As you can tell I've been working with copy/paste and I'm trying to narrow it down, line after line.

Answer (score 2):

`inline` is not a valid option for `tkz-tab`, if you try

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

you end up with

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `inline' for package `tkz-tab'.
```

---

You get nothing extra from loading packages more than once.

An option clash error occurs when you try to load a package more than once, and the options passed to the package the second time are *not* a subset of the packages passed to it the first time.

In fact, because `tkz-tab` loads `tikz` as well, I think your example can be trimmed down to the following without losing anything.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```